# Redirect from index.html to /

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, indexing

I need to make a 301 redirect to / when index.html is trying to be accesed in directory and in subdirectories.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [L,R=301]
```

When I am trying to make a redirect from example.com/index.html - everything is ok, but when I try to make a redirect from example.com/folder/index.html to example.com/folder/ it redirects to / (with the same code in .htaccess in example.com/folder/).

Please help and show the best way to organize what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to handle all these redirects from root .htaccess and avoid another .htaccess in `folder`.

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

To target specific folders:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?:folder1|folder2)/)?index\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: but what if I don't need this redirect in all folders? write some rules with folder names?